# setResolution for Datefield is not working in vaadin8

Tags: java, vaadin7, vaadin8

setResolution(Resolution.MINUTE)is not working in vaadin8 Datefield.But its working properly in vaadin 7

```
datefield.setDateformat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
datefield.setResolution(Resolution.MINUTE);
```

please help

Comment: It works for me as expected. Which version of Vaadin 8 you use? Could you describe in more detail what you expect to happen, and what actually happens. Also if you think it is a bug in the product, you should report it at https://github.com/vaadin/framework/issues instead.

Comment: iam using  vaadin version 8.4.3

Comment: You should try version 8.14.3.